# Jquery Combine Array of Arrays in another Array of Arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, for-loop

I have this Array of Arrays :

```
arr = [[1,a],[1,b],[2,c],[2,d],[3,e],[3,f]];
```

...and I would like to transform it into this:

```
arr = [[1,a,b],[2,c,d],[3,e,f]];
```

I guess it's with a 'for loop', but I don't see how to do it. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this helps you, I have replaced the values with string to get the minimal solution.

```js
let arr = [[1,'a'],[1,'b'],[2,'c'],[2,'d'],[3,'e'],[3,'f']];

arr.forEach(function(key, index){
  key.push(arr[index+1][1]);
  arr.splice(index+1, 1);
});

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: It works like a charm ! Very nice solution, very short and very effective. Many Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

i hope this helps

```js
arr = [[1,'a'],[1,'b'],[2,'c'],[2,'d'],[3,'e'],[3,'f']];


 const newArr = arr.reduce((acc, cur) => {
 const prev = acc.find(elem => elem[0] === cur[0]);

    if(prev) {
        prev[1] += ", " + cur[1];
    } 
    else {
        acc.push(cur);
    }
    return acc;
 }
 , []);

console.log(newArr);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce`. Inside the callback function check if the accumulator have a key. If not then create the key and add value to it

```js
let arr = [
  [1, 'a'],
  [1, 'b'],
  [2, 'c'],
  [2, 'd'],
  [3, 'e'],
  [3, 'f']
];

let data = arr.reduce((acc, curr) => {

  if (!acc[curr[0]]) {
    acc[curr[0]] = [];
  }
  curr.forEach((item) => {
    if (acc[curr[0]].indexOf(item) === -1) {
      acc[curr[0]].push(item);
    }
  })
  return acc;
}, {});
console.log(Object.values(data))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.